# Can Appcelerator Titanium be used to develop iPad apps?

Tags: ipad, titanium

I'm trying to find out whether Appcelerator's Titanium is good for iPad app development, or if it can even be used as such?

There seemed to be an announcement in April 2010 of a 'Titanium Tablet' package, although I can find no further mention of this. From the forums (where I've also asked this question, but  have yet to receive any responses) it *sounds* like people are developing iPad apps, but I've yet to receive a definitive answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Toby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Titanium to develop iPad apps.  There are a few iPad only UI elements in the API: [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPad-module)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply until now - I had eventually tracked down this information, but thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

Yup, Titanium works for iPad apps. Like Dave said above, there are some (two to be exact, as of today) iPad specific API's, other than those you would just use all the other existing APIs and when you create your project in Titanium Developer, you would choose iPad as the project type.

The API documentation (linked to the iPad specific APIs but the list on the left has all available ones for Mobile Dev):

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPad-module

To get an idea of what you can do, take a look at the Kitchen Sink Apps. There are two, one for the iPad, which is basic and really only shows the iPad specific API usage for the most part. The other is for the iPhone which has nearly every available API on display. They are ugly apps but they do the job of showing you what's possible and give some decent reference code. You can find the kitchen sink apps on Git hub (link below) and go here (http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/kitchensink) to see how to  run them in them the simulator (requires xCode which is free from Apple).

Also, you can find some showcased iPad apps built with titanium on the Appcelerator website (link Below), just search the page for the word iPad.

Kitchen Sink Apps :  github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink

Appcelerator Showcase :   appcelerator.com/showcase/applications-showcase/

(sorry for the non linked URLs but Github will not let you post more than one link unless you have more than 10 reputation points)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply until now - I did eventually find this information, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can build iPod, iPad, Android. BlackBerry is also available if your a paying member.
Source is also on Github if you want to have a look first.
http://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile